# How to import several .txt files at the same time?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import

I am trying to import a .txt files from a folder that contains several of them. They have the same format, CUSIP;Price;Spot;Date;Broker;

I was trying to do these, but it didnt work. Thanks, I will really apreciate it

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

path = r'C....'
files = glob(path + '/*.txt')
files
get_df = lambda f: pd.read_csv(f)
get_df

dodf = {f: get_df(f) for f in files}
```

Comment: You could try using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html) package from standard lib.

Comment: Thanks man, I will try it

Comment: Please don't use raw strings as paths. Use something OS-agnostic like [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead. It comes with standard lib and there's glob method as well.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"?

Comment: I got this error : ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 678, saw 2

Comment: Ipywidgets has a pre-fab upload widget that accepts multiple.  https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#File-Upload

Comment: It works but only upload the file. It doesnt show me the table

Comment: @Gabriel: The error occurs because it cannot read your csv file. Could you add a sample of the csv file you would like to read?

Comment: These is saved a .txt file : USIP;Price;Spot;Date;Broker;
90272V624;12.63;;03/08/2017;Cont;
9.0273E+221;1.81;;03/08/2017;Cont;
90272X851;9.55;;03/07/2017;Cont;
99658Y9U8;106.40;;02/11/2017;Citi;